# Static route use

Tags: macos, unix, routes

Using static routes is it possible to access a host with an IP address of 1.2.3.4 on port 4000 that is connect to rtrnode on a wlan network that has a public ip address of x.x.x.14 from a remote host (h1)?

h1 -------router-------INTERNET-------(public IP(x.x.14)) = rtrnode(1.2.3.3)---------destination(1.2.3.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO: Unless:You tunnel. This way the foreign LAN is a hop from the LAN you are on according to the routers on both ends that handle the packetizing and perform the VPN. It is easiest to set this up using firewalls like : PFSense or the likes. This link explains, there are many more: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/vpn-tunnel-set/. You cannot route across the Internet with static routes unless you have control over the routers that are routing. They run BGP and will direct your traffic to the valid IP you are incorrectly using in your private LAN.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!